# How to assign Subscript[C, i] to a Sum?

Tags: summation, plotting

What I want to show is:

```
Plot3D[
  Sum[1000*Subscript[C, i]^2/(1000*Subscript[C, i] - 600)^r, {i, 1, k}],
  {k, 1, 30}, {r, 0.1, 1.5}]
```

And, I want the list of `Subscript[C, i]` to be the elements of the subsets:

```
Select[Subsets[Range[30], {k}], Total[#] == 30 &]
```

For example, if `k = 2`, the results of

```
Select[Subsets[Range[30], {2}], Total[#] == 30 &]
```

is

```
{{1, 29}, {2, 28}, {3, 27}, {4, 26}, {5, 25}, {6, 24}, {7, 23}, {8, 
  22}, {9, 21}, {10, 20}, {11, 19}, {12, 18}, {13, 17}, {14, 16}}
```

Further, I want to assign `{1, 29}` to C1 and C2 of Sum firstly, and then assign `{2, 28}` to C1 and C2 of Sum secondly, etc. As a result, I will be able to get the graphic I want by `Plot3D`!

Comment: Your sum returns a list of size k, but it should return a number.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Because I want to observe a range of sum by plot3D...
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use `C` as a variable name (it is a built-in function). Also, it will be easier to use a list of the `c`s rather than subscripts. Subscript is best thought of as a typesetting function.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Could you answer my question below?

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* based on this and your other related questions you want to visualize how the number of permutations of partitions of an integer `total` of size `k` changes with `total` and `k`. (If not, comment and I'll delete this answer).

If so, something like:

```
ListPlot3D[
 Flatten[Table[{total, k, 
    Length[Join @@ 
      Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[total, {k}]]}, {total, 1, 
    30}, {k, 1, 8}], 1], PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Total", "K", "# of perms"}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Which outputs:

[image]